# How to support lowest possible API version?

Tags: android

I'm developing a Android library and I want to support as many API versions as possible. I have stumbled upon a problem with AsyncTask and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13080444/162003) here on SO. The proposed code to use is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    task.execute(params);
} else {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
}
```

My question is, how do I include the proposed code AND support lowest possible API level? What API version should I reference? What should I write in the uses-sdk tag inte manifest?

Since the field THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR in AsyncTask is only available from API level 11. Can this code be compiled to a lower level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you line below exists in you manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

This means that you are using features from API-17 but to ensure backwards compatibility your application may start on minimum API-8 (Froyo).

According to your example, using THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR for API-17 or lower is OK. And running your code with Froyo device is OK too. Because THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR field will not be used in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In the manifest set `android:minSdkVersion="minimumApiYouNeed"`, this is the lowest api you want to support, and the `android:targetSdkVersion="maximumApi"`. This is the api that will be used to compile the code. This way you will be able to do things like what you wrote there, if you ever write something that is not supported by the minimum api, the editor will notify you, but it will work well if you do the checking it will work well

Comment: targetSdkVersion does not specify the build SDK. It's specified in the project's properties file.

Comment: yea, true:), I forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use API level 11 or higher unless you can find a library that works on an earlier API level that provides the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` implementation. Also, check to see if Google provides any backports or support libraries that would allow this to work before API 11.

Answer (score 0):

This supports Android back to 2.1 (sdk version 7), but compiles the code against sdk version 17 (HoneyComb). You would have to add that tag to your manifest, of course.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Your project.properties should include this line:

```
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17
```

Comment: targetSdkVersion does not specify build SDK. It's specified in the project's properties file.