# Android AsyncTask and threading

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service, android-asynctask

I'm getting **so** tired of arm-wrestling Android in instances one steps outside the normal operation anticipated by the designers. I'd like to add that an interface contract is also behavioural and not just  a case of keeping the parameters the same. For example, the changes to the operation of AsyncTask after HONEYCOMB: it defaults to a serialized approach.

**The problem:**

We develop proprietary appplications; they'll probably never appear on Play Store and we own all the devices on which they run. We use android devices to drive all sorts of types of hardware that are connected via an RS 232 or ethernet interface.

**Background:**

I have a situation where we have an external device that periodically (asynchronously) connects to the android tablet using a TCP/IP socket. Because there's state information associated with each connection, I need to keep the IP socket up for the duration of (at least) two activities. The general flow is:

```
:start
Device ----> Connect (to android device)---->Tablet 
Device ----> Send session info-------------->Tablet
Device <---- Send response<------------------Tablet
(a new activity may start here)
Device <---- Send instruction<---------------Tablet 
Device ----> Send response------------------>Tablet
Device <---- Send instruction<---------------Tablet
Device ----> Send response------------------>Tablet
Device <---- Send instruction<---------------Tablet
Device ----> Send response------------------>Tablet
goto start
```

The above is slightly paraphrased but it gives the gist of the system.

The original approach was to have an in-process service running (associated with the application) with a separate thread that handled the asynchronous connections and marshalled the requests to and from the device. A shared object maintained the state of the server thread and connection.

However, every so often, the foreground application needs to send a command to the device. To do this, it makes sure there is an existing connection between the server and the device, locks a reentrant lock (to preclude concurrent access to the socket) and kicks off an AsyncTask which sends the command to the device and waits for the response which, in almost all cases, will come back within milliseconds. Obviously, I can't issue the socket receive on the UI thread or it'll cause a “NetworkOnMainThreadException” (the send works fine. Also, I wanted to avoid polling the result because it's tacky and inefficient. Consequently, I issue a “get(1000L)” which returns as soon as the device responds or times out before the Android “not responding” error kicks in.

This approach worked perfectly on Gingerbread, but we now need to upgrade the system to ICS or better. Unfortunately, when I issue the AsyncTask on Android versions north of Honeycomb, it never hits doInBackground. On investigation it seems, by default, anything issued on an AsyncTask only allows one thread at a time to run and it further seems that the primary service thread may count as the extra thread. (although I haven't found anything that says that definitively).

I would like to resist re-writing the entire device interface because it affects multiple products and they'd all have to be retested which, given the nature of the hardware, would be an extremely time consuming process.

So, my question is twofold:

1) Does anyone know a way to modify the AsyncTask behaviour to something with fewer thread limitation without massive code changes?

2) If not, is there a better pattern to use for this sort of problem because, if I have to do a re-write, I'd like to do it properly; preferably without having to poll anything?

I can't publish the code in entirety as it's all covered by NDA agreements but, if there are specific questions about the structure, I can probably cut out some snippets.

Comment: In question 1, I think this is what your looking for...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13080444/2315708

Answer (score 1):

I think what you seeing here are some underlying changes in threading on various Android versions.  I gather they made it so threads would run on separate cores for Android 3.? and, because so few programmers are good at actual concurrency, they turned if off again.  I think if you look at the above post you might be able to get things back to how they were.

BTW this addresses question one not two.

Comment: Yes, looks like it's a side effect of the thread changes. Pain in the backside though as I now have to write all sorts of nasty things to resynchronise the background thread and the UI thread and .join() doesn't cut it.

Comment: You seem to have accepted this is the answer, any chance of accepting it officially or maybe an up-vote.  The -1 fairies got me last week :-)

Comment: Sure - I was going to post a solution as soon as I got it working (still debugging it) - Give me a couple of hours, had to write a test harness and there's a bug in the TCP library I usually use.

Comment: apologies, I don't even have the rep to +1 you! I'd better answer a few questions myself. Modern world huh: you even have to pay school fees just to say "thanks"

Answer (score 1):

(1): The simple approach is to use [`AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29), and you can configure this quite well yourself.

(2): One pattern would be standard Java concurrency using Threads and Handlers. [Here is a good starting point.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) You would spin off a background thread and give it a handler to the UI, so it could pass messages back.

Another pattern is to use an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which may not be as well suited to the task as java concurrency.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's just a straight bug in the Android environment on ICS and above. - AsyncTask.execute() works (the new thread gets into doInBackground and does all the data exchanging). However, changing .execute() back to .get() and it never gets into doInBackground. Maybe a semi-synchronised Async task has been nerfed under the radar as it doesn't seem to be marked as "deprecated"

Comment: AsyncTask.get() is a bit pointless, IMO, as it does exactly what the AsyncTask pattern is intended to avoid. That said, since all AsyncTasks share a single executor in ICS and above, it's quite possible that other running AsyncTasks might be blocking the invocation of `get()`.

Comment: "AsyncTask.get() is a bit pointless" - then can you suggest a better way to implement a quick synchronous socket exchange? I wouldn't need to do something like this if Android didn't issue the NetworkOnMainThreadException. In this use-case, I have to stop any further activity in the App until the socket exchange has completed. So, I can either sit and poll (which is a great way to run the battery down and in such an event driven environment, must be a bad idea) or start putting flags throughout the code which is quickly going to become a maintenance problem.

Comment: I'm just going to rewrite the thing with a listener/broadcast pattern. Absurdly complicated given the simplicity of the requirement. No wonder so many apps I've downloaded from the play store crash all the time when you need this much code for trivial requirements. I'm really going off Android

Comment: I'll publish the code when I've done it as I'm sure I'm not the only person with this sort of issue

Comment: That's really more of a discussion of opinion here. I was recently working on a Windows Store App, and initially the async/await pattern seems like a wonderful idea... that is, until you get to the point where you need to control when what happens, and the Barriers unravel before you. There is no "quick synchronous socket exchange" in a mobile environment, and blocking the UI is neither a good idea, nor is it necessary.

Comment: AsyncTask doesn't need to be serialized, as I've shown above, and there are other patterns available for better control. If you have multiple consecutive requests, you don't need to but them in separate AsyncTasks, but rather than serialize them in a single task, which can be cancelable at defined steps. No polling necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the code - seems to work okay [socketserver.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1166899/socketserver.zip)

This is the business end:

```
package com.retailsci.socketserver;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: paul
 * Date: 2013/08/12
 * Time: 9:06 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream  ;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream ;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter   ;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle ;
import android.os.IBinder ;
import android.os.RemoteException ;
import android.view.View ;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener ;
import android.widget.Button ;
import android.widget.Toast ;
import android.widget.TextView ;
import android.util.Log ;
import android.os.Handler;
import org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils;

public class ServerThread implements Runnable
{
    public static final String    TAG = "RetailScience::ServerThread"    ;
    public static final int       READ_OPERATION        = 1 ;
    public static final int       WRITE_OPERATION       = 2 ;
    public static final int       READLENGTH_OPERATION  = 3 ;
    public static final int       WRITELENGTH_OPERATION = 4 ;

    int                           ServerPort     ;
    ServerSocket                  serverSocket   ;
    Socket                        client         ;
    boolean                       Connected      ;
    String                        IPAddress      ;
    CircularByteBuffer            InDataBuffer   ;
    CircularByteBuffer            OutDataBuffer  ;

    public ServerThread (int ServerPort)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "constructor - start") ;

        this.ServerPort = ServerPort ;

        IPAddress = IPv4Address() ;

        Log.v(TAG, "constructor - end") ;
    }

    public boolean isConnected ()
    {
        return(Connected) ;
    }

    public String getIPAddress ()
    {
        return (IPAddress) ;
    }

    public void closeAll ()
    {
        Connected = false ; /* set the connection state */

        Log.v(TAG, "Closing all the sessions");

        try
        {
            client.close () ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Thread - Exception on Client Close " + e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            serverSocket.close () ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Thread - Exception on serverSocket Close " + e.toString());
        }

        serverSocket  = null ;
        client        = null ;
        InDataBuffer  = null ;
        OutDataBuffer = null ;

        System.gc() ;

        /* Make sure the other threads can have a go now */
        Thread.yield () ;
    }

    public boolean write (byte [] data, int offset, int length)
    {
        boolean okay = false ;

        if (isConnected ())
        {
            try
            {
                OutDataBuffer.getOutputStream().write (data, offset, length) ;
                okay = true ;
                Thread.yield() ; /* Give the background thread a chance */
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                Log.e(TAG, "UI Thread - Probably a Connection Exception " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        return (okay) ;
    }

    public void flush () /* Clear out anything in the IC buffers */
    {
        if (isConnected ())
        {
            try
            {
                int  BytesReady = 0 ;

                do
                {
                    Thread.yield() ; /* Give the background thread a chance */

                    BytesReady = InDataBuffer.getInputStream().available () ;

                    Log.v(TAG, "FLUSH bytes" + BytesReady) ;

                    if (BytesReady > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] junk = new byte [BytesReady] ;
                        InDataBuffer.getInputStream().read (junk, 0, BytesReady) ;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep (50) ; /* Give the other thread time to pull */
                                        /* anything else out of the IC buffer */
                }
                while (BytesReady > 0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                Log.e(TAG, "UI Thread - Probably a Connection Exception " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }


    public int available ()
    {
        int  BytesReady = -1 ;

        if (isConnected ())
        {
            try
            {
                BytesReady = InDataBuffer.getInputStream().available () ;

                if (BytesReady > 0)
                {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Bytes in incoming buffer " + BytesReady) ;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                Log.e(TAG, "UI Thread - Probably a Connection Exception " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        return (BytesReady) ;
    }

    public int read (byte [] data, int offset, int length) throws IOException
    {
        int  BytesRead = -1 ;

        if (isConnected ())
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "*********  reading data " + length) ;
            try
            {
                BytesRead           = 0 ;
                int totalBytesRcvd  = 0 ; // Total bytes received so far

                while (totalBytesRcvd < length)
                {
                    if ((BytesRead =
                         InDataBuffer.getInputStream().read (data,
                                                             totalBytesRcvd + offset,
                                                             length - totalBytesRcvd)) == -1)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "UI Thread Connection Exception in Read");
                        throw new SocketException("Connection closed prematurely");
                    }

                    Log.v(TAG, "*********  bytes read " + BytesRead) ;
                    totalBytesRcvd += BytesRead ;

                    Log.v(TAG, "*********  total bytes read " + totalBytesRcvd) ;
                }
                BytesRead = length ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                Log.e(TAG, "UI Thread - Probably a Connection Exception " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        return (BytesRead) ;
    }

    //---get the local IPv4 address---
    // Taken from "Android(TM) Application Development Cookbook", by Wei-Meng Lee
    // p. 212
    // (Very useful book by the way)
    private String IPv4Address()
    {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceEnum = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); networkInterfaceEnum
                    .hasMoreElements();)
            {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaceEnum.nextElement();

                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> ipAddressEnum
                     = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); ipAddressEnum.hasMoreElements();)
                {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) ipAddressEnum.nextElement();
                    // ---check that it is not a loopback address and
                    // it is IPv4---
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                        &&
                        InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress()))
                    {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IPv4Address " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IPAddress != null)
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "Starting...");
                // handler.post(new Runnable()
                //     {
                //          @Override
                //          public void run()
                //          {
                //              textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                //                                + "Server listening on IP: " + SERVER_IP
                //                                + "\n");
                //          }
                //     });

                //---create an instance of the server socket---
                //--- Allow 2 outstanding connections
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerPort, 1);

                /* allow the socket to be reused - or we'll get INUSE exception*/
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true) ;

                int Counter = 0 ;
                Log.v(TAG, "Server Thread Running");

                while (true)
                {
                    //---wait for incoming clients---
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                    Log.v(TAG, "Connection Detected");
                    Connected = true ; /* set the connection state */

                    //---the above code is a blocking call;
                    // i.e. it will block until a client connects---
                    try
                    {
                        InDataBuffer                                = new CircularByteBuffer() ;
                        OutDataBuffer                               = new CircularByteBuffer() ;

                        BufferedInputStream         InStream      = new BufferedInputStream   (client.getInputStream()) ;
                        BufferedOutputStream        OutStream     = new BufferedOutputStream  (client.getOutputStream()) ;
                        int                         BytesDataBuffer ;

                        while (true)
                        {
                            if (Counter >= 1500) /* About 15 seconds */
                            {
                                /* Done' print this out too often */
                                Counter = 0 ;
                                Log.v(TAG, "Server Thread Running");
                            }
                            ++Counter ;

                            BytesDataBuffer = InStream.available() ;

                            if (BytesDataBuffer > 0)
                            {
                                Log.v(TAG, "Reading Data Bytes " + BytesDataBuffer);

                                byte [] TempBuffer = new byte [BytesDataBuffer] ;

                                InStream.read (TempBuffer, 0, BytesDataBuffer) ;
                                InDataBuffer.getOutputStream().write (TempBuffer, 0, BytesDataBuffer);

                                Log.v(TAG, "Read Data Bytes " + BytesDataBuffer);
                            }

                            BytesDataBuffer = OutDataBuffer.getInputStream().available() ;

                            if (BytesDataBuffer > 0)
                            {
                                Log.v(TAG, "Writing Data Bytes " + BytesDataBuffer);

                                byte [] TempBuffer = new byte [BytesDataBuffer] ;

                                OutDataBuffer.getInputStream().read (TempBuffer, 0, BytesDataBuffer) ;
                                OutStream.write (TempBuffer, 0, BytesDataBuffer);
                                OutStream.flush() ; /* Make sure the buffer is empty */

                                Log.v(TAG, "Wrote Data Bytes " + BytesDataBuffer);
                            }

                            Thread.sleep(100) ; /* Always yield for a bit */
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Thread - Read Exception " + e.toString());
                        Connected = false ; /* set the connection state */
                    }

                } /*    while (true)    */
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Thread - No Network Capability");
                Connected = false ; /* set the connection state */
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Thread - Probably a Connection Exception" + e.toString());
            Connected = false ; /* set the connection state */
        }

        closeAll () ;
        Log.v(TAG, "*********************************************** Socket Thread - Connection Terminated");
        Log.v(TAG, "*********************************************** Socket Thread - Connection Terminated");
        Log.v(TAG, "*********************************************** Socket Thread - Connection Terminated");
        Log.v(TAG, "*********************************************** Socket Thread - Connection Terminated");
    }
}
```

Examples of reading and writing are in: DeviceIF.java (in the zip file) however, here are a few of the main primitives:

```
    ServerThread                  SocketIF ;
    Thread                        BackgroundThread  ;


To start it
          SocketIF         = new ServerThread (12347) ; /* 12347 is the server I/C port */
          BackgroundThread = new Thread(SocketIF);
          BackgroundThread.setDaemon(true) ; /* Make this a Daemon Thread */
          BackgroundThread.start();


To stop it                
          SocketIF.closeAll () ;
          Thread.yield () ; /* give the thread time to find out it's dead */

          if (BackgroundThread != null)
          {
             if (BackgroundThread.isAlive())
             {
                 BackgroundThread.interrupt (); /* Get rid of the thread */
                 Thread.yield () ; /* give the thread time to find out it's dead */
             }
          }

To read
        try
        {
            if (SocketIF.isConnected ())
            {
                byte []   ResponseBuffer = new byte [7] ;
                int Result = SocketIF.read (ResponseBuffer, 0, 7) ;
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage() ;
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + error);
        }

To Write
       int Result = ERROR_FAILED ;

        try
        {
            if (SocketIF.isConnected ()) /* see if it's still open */
            {
                // flushICData () ; Good idea to do this before you issue a request

                int             RequestLen = 0 ;
                final byte []   RequestBuffer  = new byte [20] ;

                RequestBuffer [RequestLen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* This will eventually hold the length */
                RequestBuffer [RequestLen++] = (byte) '1' ;

                RequestBuffer [0] = (byte) ((RequestLen - 1) & 0xFF) ; /* Put in the length one byte's enough */

                SocketIF.write (RequestBuffer, 0, RequestLen) ;

                Result = ERROR_OKAY ;
            }
            else
            {
                Result = ERROR_NO_CONNECTION ;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage() ;
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + error);
            Result = ERROR_EXCEPTION ;
        }
```

Before I get a load of aggro, I'm aware of some of the deficiencies in the architecture; I kept it simple to make it easier to follow (which is why I didn't wrap the read/write stuff in a stream). I didn't put timeouts in the reads either, but that would be a doddle to add.

The code I've borrowed from other sources is indicated in the source:

- Working timer - Used because there's a problem cancelling the default
  android CountdownTimer from within a tick event Circular buffer -
  Used to provide a nice simple circular buffer stream to allow
  asynchrounous reading and writing from the server. The IP4Addess code
  came from Android(TM) Application Development Cookbook", by Wei-Meng
  Lee p. 212 (great book by the way)

(I can't put the URL links to the latter code in because I don't have enough rep to post more than two f***** links)

For the purposes of illustration, here's how to handle incoming data if there's a significant delay between writing to the data stream and getting a response back. This is called from the onTick event in Countdowntimer (Workingtimer in my case because of the timer cancel problem mentioned above)

```
protected void TickHandler ()
{
    try
    {
        /* See if we have connected yet */
        if (TerminalIF.isConnected ())
        {
            /* See if we have connected yet */
            Button btn ;

            btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.getpinbutton);
            btn.setEnabled(true) ;

            btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.displaybutton);
            btn.setEnabled(true) ;

            btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.getcardstatebutton);
            btn.setEnabled(true) ;

            btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.rebootbutton);
            btn.setEnabled(true) ;

            btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.pingbutton);
            btn.setEnabled(true) ;

            if (TerminalIF.responseReady ())
            {
                byte [] DataResult = TerminalIF.ReceivePacket () ;
                Log.v(TAG, "Data Received") ;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Device Data Received",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;

                resetTimer (DEFAULT_INPUT_TIMER_TIMEOUT) ;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage() ;
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + error);
    }
}
```

Yes, I could have done it with AsyncTasks and handlers but this is a straight drop-in module that can be used pretty much anywhere with little modification. It would be pretty easy to convert into a service too.

And, before I get told off for being irrelevant, verbose or answering my own question, I just thought I'd share the work.

One final thing, here's a little test harness to try it out with:

PINPad.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.* ;

public class PINPad
{
    InputStream  in  ;
    OutputStream out ;

    byte [] receive (int len) throws IOException
    {
        byte [] result = null ;

        if (len > 0)
        {
            byte [] temp = new byte [len] ;

            // Receive the same string back from the server
            int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Total bytes received so far
            int bytesRcvd ;          // Bytes received in last read

            while (totalBytesRcvd < temp.length)
            {
              if ((bytesRcvd = in.read(temp, totalBytesRcvd, temp.length - totalBytesRcvd)) == -1)
              {
                  System.out.println("Error on receive");
                  throw new SocketException("Connection closed prematurely");
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("Received " + bytesRcvd + " bytes");
              }

              totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
            } // data array is full

            result = temp ;
        }

        return result ;
    }

    void send (byte [] data, int offset, int len) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Sending.... " + len + " bytes");
        if (len > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                out.write (data, offset, len) ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error on send");
                throw new SocketException("Connection closed prematurely");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sent " + len + " bytes");
    }

    void loop (Socket  echoSocket)
    {
        boolean okay = true ;

        try
        {
            in  = echoSocket.getInputStream();
            out = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            okay = false ;
        }

        while (okay)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Receive length");
                byte [] len = receive (1) ;

                int packetlength = (int) len[0] ;
                System.out.println("Subsequent packet length = " + packetlength);


                byte [] packet = receive (packetlength) ;

                System.out.println("Got a packet of = " + packet.length);

                char    packettype = (char) packet [0] ;
                byte [] retbuf = new byte [50] ;
                int     reqlen = 0 ;

                switch (packettype)
                {
                    case 'A' :  /* PING */
                        System.out.println("==== PING");
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* placeholder for the length */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) packettype ;
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '0' ;   /* Error code  = OK */
                        retbuf [0]        = (byte) (reqlen - 1) ;  /* Now put the length in */

                        send(retbuf, 0, reqlen);
                        break ;

                    case 'B' : /* GET PIN */
                        System.out.println("==== GET PIN");
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* placeholder for the length */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) packettype ;
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '0' ;   /* Error code  = OK */
                        retbuf [0]        = (byte) (reqlen - 1) ;  /* Now put the length in */

                        send(retbuf, 0, reqlen);
                        break ;

                    case 'C' : /* GET CARD STATE */
                        System.out.println("==== GET CARD STATE");
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* placeholder for the length */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) packettype ;
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '0' ;  /* Error code  = OK */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '1' ;  /* Card is present */
                        retbuf [0]        = (byte) (reqlen - 1) ;  /* Now put the length in */

                        send(retbuf, 0, reqlen);
                        break ;

                    case 'D' : /* DISPLAY */
                        System.out.println("==== DISPLAY");
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* placeholder for the length */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) packettype ;
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '0' ;  /* Error code  = OK */
                        retbuf [0]        = (byte) (reqlen - 1) ;  /* Now put the length in */

                        send(retbuf, 0, reqlen);
                        break ;

                    case 'E' : /* REBOOT */
                        System.out.println("==== REBOOT");
                        okay = false ;
                        break ;

                    case 'F' : /* CLOSE */
                        System.out.println("==== CLOSE SESSION");
                        okay = false ;
                        break ;

                    default :
                        System.out.println("==== UNKNOWN!!!!!!");
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) 0 ;  /* placeholder for the length */
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) packettype ;
                        retbuf [reqlen++] = (byte) '3' ;  /* error */
                        retbuf [0]        = (byte) (reqlen - 1) ;  /* Now put the length in */

                        send(retbuf, 0, reqlen);
                        break ;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                okay = false ;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            okay = false ;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Socket          echoSocket = null;
        PINPad          IF = new PINPad () ;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.168.106", 12347);

                // out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                // in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

                if (echoSocket != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Connected to remote");
                    IF.loop (echoSocket) ;

                    echoSocket.close();
                    System.out.println("Waiting for next connection");
                }
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Don't know about host: 192.168.168.107.");
                // System.exit(1);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: 192.168.168.107.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: 192.168.168.107.");
            }

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (1000) ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Thread Interrupted....");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```